# MongoDB with Java - Find() with BETWEEN

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the SQL

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE data BETWEEN '2015-08-26' AND '2015-08-26'
```

in MongoDB

```
MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection("venda");

AggregateIterable<Document> mongoCollectionList = coll.aggregate(
       Arrays.asList(
             Aggregates.match(Filters.and(Filters.gte("data", "2015-08-26"), 
                                          Filters.lte("data", "2015-08-26"))),
             Aggregates.project(fields(excludeId())
        ));
```

The correct is to use the *ISODate*

How do i convert '**2015-08-26**' to '**2015-08-26T02:00:00Z**' ?

Tks"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Java 8` to parse the ISO string date to `Instant` and back to `Date` for Mongo DB driver.

You don't need aggregation for your use case.

```
 Instant start = LocalDate.parse("2015-08-26").atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
 Instant end = LocalDate.parse("2015-08-26").atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
 MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection("venda");
 FindIterable<Document> mongoCollectionList = coll.find(Filters.and(Filters.gte("data", 
                  Date.from(start)), Filters.lte("data",  Date.from(end)))).projection(excludeId());
```

Java 7 update:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date start = format.parse("2015-08-26");
Date end = format.parse("2015-08-26");
```

Comment: I use because this a part of the code ^^ And in Java 7.  It exist another form?